# Чат на php и ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, с добавлением онлайн записей. Сделал чат: пользователь добавляет сообщение, оно записывается в файл letters.dat. Далее записи выводятся. В этом же чате удобнее было бы использовать онлайн добавление. Обновлять каждые 5 секунд не лучший способ, может быть ajax поможет? Как можно это организовать?

Answer (score 3):

Вы действительно думаете что дядя Ajax - это нечто такое, что избавит ва,с от необходимости, что-то обновлять каждые 5 секунд?  Вы будете разочарованы, но - это всего лишь технология, позволяющая делать асинхронные запросы, к серверу, в народе говорят проще, без перезагрузки страницы. Нужно следовать правила и стандартам. Я так понимаю, вы сотворили чат, через фрейм, с рефрешем в 5 секунд, так вот, аякс -  это будет то-же самое, только без фрейма. Я полагаю, вас интересует, что-то вроде постоянного соединения с сервером, через Commet.

[dklab_multiplexor: постоянное Javascript-соединение с сервером в условиях сотен тысяч онлайн-клиентов](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/hi/69457/)